# Air-conditioner in heat mode

Tags: air-conditioning

When a split unit air-conditioner is used in heat mode, does it dry out the air inside the house/room? If so, is it advisable to use a Humidifier in conjunction with the air conditioner in winter months?

Comment: no it does not dry out the air ... there is no water going down the drain ... warm air is able to hold more moisture than cold air, so the rative humidity of the warm air is lower

Answer (score 1):

Air conditioners cool by running air through a cold coil (the evaporator). If the evaporator cools the air below the dew point, then water condenses, drying out the air. The excess heat is put outdoors using a hot coil (the condenser).

When you run a mini-split in reverse, it changes the evaporator into a condenser, which gives off the heat collected from the outside coil (now an evaporator). This heats the air, but it does nothing to the humidity, since the air never goes below the dew point.